# RowFilter.regexFilter não filtra colunas do tipo Date na JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, rowfilter

Tenho uma `JTable` com um `TableModel` customizado, e estou tentando fazer funcionar uma campo de pesquisa usando `JTextField`. Porém, as colunas do tipo `Date` e da minha classe `Cadastrante` não são pesquisadas.

No meu `TableModel`, sobrescrevi o método `getColumnClass()` dessa forma:

```
    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        switch (columnIndex) {
            case OFICIO:
                return Integer.class;
            case PROTOCOLO:
                return Long.class;
            case ASSUNTO:
                return String.class;
            case DATA:
                return Date.class;
            case CADASTRANTE:
                //Cadastrante é minha custom class
                return Cadastrante.class;
            default:
                return super.getColumnClass(columnIndex);
        }
    }
```

E o método `getValueAt()` está assim:

```
@Override
public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    Oficio oficio = this.oficios.get(rowIndex);
    switch (columnIndex) {
        case OFICIO:
            return oficio.getCodigo();
        case PROTOCOLO:
            if (oficio.getProtocolo() == 0) {
                return null;
            }
            return oficio.getProtocolo();
        case ASSUNTO:
            return oficio.getAssunto();
        case DATA:
            // retorna um objeto do tipo util.Date  
            return oficio.getData();
        case CADASTRANTE:
            // retorna um objeto do tipo Cadastrante
            return oficio.getCadastrante();
        case SETOR:
            return oficio.getSetor().getNome();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Na minha tela principal, onde fica a `JTable`, eu inicio uma variável do tipo `TableRowSorter`, passando o `TableModel` como argumento, e `seto` essa variável como `RowSorter` da minha tabela:

```
    this.linhasFiltradas = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(this.tabela.getModel());
    this.tabela.setRowSorter(linhasFiltradas);
```

Adicionei um *listener* no `JTextField` para que, quando o <kbd>ENTER</kbd> for pressionado, efetuar o filtro com o digitado nesse campo:

```
private void fieldFiltroBarKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                           
    if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
        JTextField field = (JTextField) evt.getSource();
        String busca = field.getText().trim();
        linhasFiltradas.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + busca));
    }
}
```

Nas colunas que declarei o tipo como `Date.class` e `Cadastrante.class`, a pesquisa parece ignorar, mesmo se eu digitar termos exibidos nessas colunas, para as demais, a pesquisa localiza normalmente.

No caso da minha classe `Cadastrante`, ao debugar o trecho correspondente, descobri que o `RowSorter` tenta invocar o método `toString()`, e como não encontra, ele parece ignorar minha classe por não saber como acessar o conteúdo dela. Sobrescrevendo esse método dentro da minha classe(retorno o nome, ele que é exibido pelo renderer da tabela), essa coluna passa a ser pesquisável, mas para a coluna que retorna `Date` eu não consegui fazer funcionar.

Segue o renderer da tabela:

```
public class OficioTableRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

    private final int COLUNA_ASSUNTO = 2;
    private final int COLUNA_DATA = 3;
    private final int COLUNA_CADASTRANTE = 4;

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
        switch (column) {
            case COLUNA_ASSUNTO:
                setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
                setFont(new Font("Tahoma", 0, 11));
                break;
            case COLUNA_DATA:
                setText(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(value));
                setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
                setFont(new Font(null, 0, 14));
                break;
            case COLUNA_CADASTRANTE:
                Cadastrante cad = (Cadastrante) value;
                setText(cad.getNome());
                setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
                setFont(new Font(null, 0, 14));
                break;
            default:
                setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
                setFont(new Font(null, 0, 14));
                break;
        } 
        setForeground(Color.black);
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    protected void setValue(Object value) {
        super.setValue(value); 
    }      
}
```

Como faço para tornar a coluna `Date` pesquisável também?

Comment: Como está o método `getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex)` da sua `TableModel`?

Comment: @VictorStafusa adicionei na pergunta o método .

Comment: Como o seu renderer funciona?

Comment: @VictorStafusa adicionei na pergunta. No caso da coluna Date, eu aplico a mascara do formato BR e a data aparece  normalmente como `dd/MM/yyyy`. Sem o renderer, a data é exibida em formato americano, com traços.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solução seria usar uma *custom class* para encapsular o `Date`:

```
public class DateHelper implements Comparable<DateHelper> {
    private final Date date;

    private DateHelper(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public static DateHelper of(Date date) {
        return date == null ? null : new DateHelper(date);
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(DateHelper other) {
        return date.compareTo(other.date);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (!(other instanceof DateHelper)) return false;
        return date.equals(((DateHelper) other).date);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return date.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(date);
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }
}
```

Isso acarretará algumas mudanças na sua `TableModel`:

```
@Override
public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
    switch (columnIndex) {
        case OFICIO:
            return Integer.class;
        case PROTOCOLO:
            return Long.class;
        case ASSUNTO:
            return String.class;
        case DATA:
            return DateHelper.class;
        case CADASTRANTE:
            //Cadastrante é minha custom class
            return Cadastrante.class;
        default:
            return super.getColumnClass(columnIndex);
    }
}

@Override
public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    Oficio oficio = this.oficios.get(rowIndex);
    switch (columnIndex) {
        case OFICIO:
            return oficio.getCodigo();
        case PROTOCOLO:
            if (oficio.getProtocolo() == 0) {
                return null;
            }
            return oficio.getProtocolo();
        case ASSUNTO:
            return oficio.getAssunto();
        case DATA:
            // retorna um objeto do tipo DateHelper 
            return DateHelper.of(oficio.getData());
        case CADASTRANTE:
            // retorna um objeto do tipo Cadastrante
            return oficio.getCadastrante();
        case SETOR:
            return oficio.getSetor().getNome();
    }
    return null;
}
```

E por fim, no seu renderer:

```
        case COLUNA_DATA:
            setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            setFont(new Font(null, 0, 14));
            break;
```

Comment: O que é  `other.date`? Está acessando a propriedade private da classe de outro objeto do mesmo tipo?

Comment: @DiegoF Sim. Está acessando o campo `date` do outro objeto da mesma classe.

Comment: O fato dele ser `private` não impede o acesso?

Comment: @DiegoF Não, porque as regras de restrição de acesso são baseadas em classes e não em instâncias. Como é um outro objeto da mesma classe, então isso é permitido.

Comment: Obrigado, atendeu perfeitamente e nem precisei mudar nada no `setValueAt` e nem na classe `Oficio` :)

Comment: victor, como faço para recuperar o Date de um DateHelper? Encontrei uma situação no código onde precisei pegar o Date, ai estourou ClassCastException por causa das classes diferentes.

Comment: @DiegoF É só colocar um getter nele. Editei a resposta para ter isso também.

Comment: Eu consegui retornar, fiz um método `public Date parse(){return date;}` e resolveu.