# Como aplicar um filtro de dois JDateChooser a uma JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcalendar

Preciso filtrar os dados simultaneamente para serem exibidos em uma `JTable`. Consultando algumas perguntas antigas eu consegui resolver parte meu problema.

Tenho um campo DATA na tabela do tipo String e tenho dois `JDateChooser` da lib JCalendar na interface. Preciso pegar estas datas e ver se a data da tabela está entre o intervalo selecionado no `JDateChooser`.

Mas não tenho ideia de como fazer esta verificação. Fiz um exemplo bem simples, nem coloquei campo para pesquisar pelo nome mas escrevi no código como se tivesse para verem como eu implementei a busca e funcionou.

Matricula

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollBar;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.RowFilter;
import javax.swing.RowFilter.ComparisonType;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter;

public class Matricula extends JFrame {

    private static final int ITENS_POR_PAG = 5;

    public Matricula() {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {

        jScrollPane = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        table = new javax.swing.JTable();
        btnFirst = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btnPrevious = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btnNext = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btnLast = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btnFiltrar = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jdcDataDeInicio = new com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser();
        lblDe = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        lblAte = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jdcDataDeFim = new com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jdcDataDeInicio.setDateFormatString("dd/MM/yyyy");
        jdcDataDeFim.setDateFormatString("dd/MM/yyyy");

        TableModel tableModel = table.getModel();
        sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(tableModel);
        table.setRowSorter(sorter);

        model = new MatriculaTableModel(JSONUtils.JSONtoList());

        table = new JTable(model);

        jScrollPane = new JScrollPane(table, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER,
                JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        jScrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(getPreferredSize().width - 20, table.getRowHeight() * ITENS_POR_PAG + table.getTableHeader().getPreferredSize().height));

        jScrollPane.setViewportView(table);

        btnFirst.setText("<<");

        btnPrevious.setText("<");

        btnNext.setText(">");

        btnLast.setText(">>");

        btnFiltrar.setText("Filtrar");

        lblDe.setText("De");

        lblAte.setText("Até");

        btnFirst = new JButton("<<");
        btnFirst.addActionListener(e -> {
            JScrollBar bar = jScrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar();
            bar.setValue(0);
        });

        btnPrevious = new JButton("<");
        btnPrevious.addActionListener(e -> {
            int height = table.getRowHeight() * (ITENS_POR_PAG);
            JScrollBar bar = jScrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar();
            bar.setValue(bar.getValue() - height);
        });

        btnNext = new JButton(">");
        btnNext.addActionListener(e -> {
            int height = table.getRowHeight() * (ITENS_POR_PAG);
            JScrollBar bar = jScrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar();
            bar.setValue(bar.getValue() + height);
        });

        btnLast = new JButton(">>");
        btnLast.addActionListener(e -> {
            JScrollBar bar = jScrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar();
            bar.setValue(bar.getMaximum());
        });

        btnFiltrar.addActionListener(e -> {
            aplicaFiltros();
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addComponent(btnFirst)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(lblDe)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addComponent(jdcDataDeInicio, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(btnPrevious)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(btnNext)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(btnLast)
                        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(lblAte)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jdcDataDeFim, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 87, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(btnFiltrar)))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jScrollPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 207, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(btnFirst)
                    .addComponent(btnPrevious)
                    .addComponent(btnNext)
                    .addComponent(btnLast))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 30, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(btnFiltrar)
                        .addComponent(lblAte))
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                        .addComponent(lblDe)
                        .addComponent(jdcDataDeInicio, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addComponent(jdcDataDeFim, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }                      

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Matricula.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Matricula.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Matricula.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Matricula.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Matricula().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public void aplicaFiltros(){

        //String nome = txtNome.getText().trim();
      Date dataInicio = jdcDataDeInicio.getDate(),
              dataFim = jdcDataDeFim.getDate();

        Set<RowFilter<Object, Object>> filtrosTabela = new HashSet<>();
        //filtrosTabela.add(RowFilter.regexFilter(nome, 1));

        filtrosTabela.add( RowFilter.dateFilter(ComparisonType.AFTER, dataInicio, 2));
        filtrosTabela.add( RowFilter.dateFilter(ComparisonType.BEFORE, dataFim, 2));


        sorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.andFilter(filtrosTabela));

    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton btnFiltrar;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnFirst;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnLast;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnNext;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnPrevious;
    private JScrollPane jScrollPane;
    private com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser jdcDataDeFim;
    private com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser jdcDataDeInicio;
    private javax.swing.JLabel lblAte;
    private javax.swing.JLabel lblDe;
    private javax.swing.JTable table;
    private MatriculaTableModel model;
    private TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

MatriculaModel

```
public class MatriculaModel {
    private boolean selecionado;
    private String nome;
    private Date data;

    public boolean getSelecionado() {
        return selecionado;
    }

    public void setSelecionado(boolean selecionado) {
        this.selecionado = selecionado;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public Date getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(Date data) {
        this.data = data;
    }


}
```

MatriculaTableModel

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class MatriculaTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {


    private List<MatriculaModel> dados = new ArrayList<>();
    private String[] colunas = {"Selecionar", "Nome", "Data"};

    public MatriculaTableModel(List<MatriculaModel> model) {
        this.dados = model;
    }


    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        return columnIndex == 0 ? Boolean.class : super.getColumnClass(columnIndex);
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int column){
        return colunas[column];
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return colunas.length;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return dados.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int linha, int coluna) {
        switch(coluna){
            case 0:
                return dados.get(linha).getSelecionado();
            case 1:
                return dados.get(linha).getNome();
            case 2:
                return dados.get(linha).getData();
        }

        return null;
    }

    public void setValueAt(Object valor, int linha, int coluna) {
        MatriculaModel tm = dados.get(linha);
        switch (coluna) {
        case 0:
            tm.setSelecionado(new Boolean((Boolean) valor));
            break;
        }
        fireTableDataChanged();
    }

    public void addRow(MatriculaModel tm) {
        this.dados.add(tm);
        this.fireTableDataChanged();    
    }

    public void removeRow(int linha){
        this.dados.remove(linha);
        this.fireTableRowsDeleted(linha, linha);
    }

    public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return columnIndex == 0; 
    }

    public void deletarLinhas() {
        this.dados.clear();
        this.fireTableDataChanged();
    }

}
```

JSONUtils

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

public class JSONUtils {

    private static String strjson = null;

    private JSONUtils() {

        if (strjson == null)
            strjson = lerArquivo();
    }

    public static List<MatriculaModel> JSONtoList() {
        String str = lerArquivo();
        Type type = new TypeToken<List<MatriculaModel>>() {
        }.getType();

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").create();
        List<MatriculaModel> lista = gson.fromJson(str, type);

        for (MatriculaModel teste : lista) {
            System.out.println(teste.getSelecionado());
            System.out.println(teste.getNome());
        }
        return lista;
    }

    private static String lerArquivo() {
        String linha = "";

        try {
            FileReader arq = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\maily\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Matricula\\src\\matricula\\dados.json");
            BufferedReader lerArq = new BufferedReader(arq);

            linha = lerArq.readLine();
            /*
             * while (linha != null) { System.out.printf(linha); linha = lerArq.readLine();
             * // lê da segunda até a última linha }
             */
            arq.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.printf("Erro na abertura do arquivo: %s.\n", e.getMessage());
        }
        // System.out.println(linha);
        return linha;
    }
}
```

dados.json

```
[{"selecionado": false, "nome": "João", "data": "23/10/2000"}, {"selecionado": false, "nome": "Maria", "data": "03/05/2006"}, {"selecionado": false, "nome": "Pedro", "data": "30/02/2002"}, {"selecionado": false, "nome": "Laura", "data": "03/07/2008"}, {"selecionado": false, "nome": "Manoel", "data": "05/11/2018"}, {"selecionado": false, "nome": "João", "data": "23/10/2000"}, {"selecionado": false, "nome": "Maria", "data": "03/05/2006"}, {"selecionado": false, "nome": "Pedro", "data": "30/02/2002"}, {"selecionado": false, "nome": "Laura", "data": "03/07/2008"}, {"selecionado": false, "nome": "Manoel", "data": "05/11/2018"}, {"selecionado": false, "nome": "João", "data": "23/10/2000"}, {"selecionado": false, "nome": "Maria", "data": "03/05/2006"}, {"selecionado": false, "nome": "Pedro", "data": "30/02/2002"}, {"selecionado": false, "nome": "Laura", "data": "03/07/2008"}, {"selecionado": false, "nome": "Manoel", "data": "05/11/2018"}]
```

Baixar libs: [JCalendar](http://www.toedter.com/download/jcalendar-1.4.zip), [Gson](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.8.5/gson-2.8.5.jar)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu filtro não funciona devido a, especificamente, este trecho:

```
TableModel tableModel = table.getModel();
sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(tableModel);
table.setRowSorter(sorter);

model = new MatriculaTableModel(JSONUtils.JSONtoList());

table = new JTable(model);
```

Você está criando um model local vazio e passando ele para seu `RowSorter`, e logo abaixo, você cria outro e passa para a tabela. Obviamente o filtro nunca irá funcionar, pois além de não ter dados nesse model local que ele recebeu, o model da tabela é completamente diferente do que foi passado para ele.

Outro erro é que você está definindo o rowsorter pra tabela criada vazia e depois cria outra por cima.

Primeiro deve-se criar o TableModel, depois defini-lo como model da tabela, para então criar o rowsorter baseado naquele TableModel e definir para a tabela, como abaixo:

```
model = new MatriculaTableModel(JSONUtils.JSONtoList());
table.setModel(model);
sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(model);
table.setRowSorter(sorter);
```

Dessa forma, o filtro funciona normalmente:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Um código não deve ser apenas copiado, deve ser entendido, senão você sempre cometerá os mesmos erros como na pergunta anterior, de usar componentes sem ao menos entender como eles funcionam. E para entender o funcionamento, é sempre importante visitar a página da documentação da classe.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: @lys pra exibir a data corretamente, veja essa resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/122302/28595

Comment: Resolveu o formato da data porém o filtro parou de funcionar. Obrigado!

Comment: @lys bom, realmente pra solução acima teria q adaptar. Mas ao inves disso, olhe o TableCellRenderer que eu coloquei nesta mesmo pergunta. Nele eu renderizo um campo de data, sem alterar o tipo Date. Se chama "COLUNA_DATA", só criar um tablecellrenderer e aplicar a coluna de data.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado pela dica. Foi realmente muito útil.